# Getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 2), but I believe I'm passing two

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` even though I'm passing two arguments.

I am attempting to anyways..

Here is the app trace.

```
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:6:in `initialize'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:82:in `new'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in ips_dashboard'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:81:in `each'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:81:in `block in ips_dashboard'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:74:in `each'
app/controllers/ips_dashboard_controller.rb:74:in `ips_dashboard'
```

Here I'm looking up ip addresses in the db and passing the array to the `IP_data` class to use in Seer::visualize.

```
# Begin lookups for tgt addresses
target_ip_data = Array.new
@tgt_ip_array = Array.new
@events.each do |ip_event|
  def get_target_ip(sid,cid)
    IpsIpHdr.where('sid =? and cid =?', sid, cid).first.ip_dst
  end
  tgt_ip = get_target_ip(ip_event.sid, ip_event.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')
  target_ip_data.push(tgt_ip)
  @tgt_ip_hash = Hash[target_ip_data.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
  @tgt_ip_hash.each do |t|
    @tgt_ip_array.push(IP_data.new(:ip => t[0],:count => t[1]))
  end
end
# End lookups for tgt addresses
```

I also tried this, but also got an error. `undefined method 'ip' for ["172.31.251.13", 24]:Array`

```
# Begin lookups for tgt addresses
target_ip_data = Array.new
@tgt_ip_array = Array.new
@events.each do |ip_event|
  def get_target_ip(sid,cid)
    IpsIpHdr.where('sid =? and cid =?', sid, cid).first.ip_dst
  end
  tgt_ip = get_target_ip(ip_event.sid, ip_event.cid).to_s(16).rjust(8,'0').scan(/.{2}/).map(&:hex).join('.')
  target_ip_data.push(tgt_ip)
  @tgt_ip_hash = Hash[target_ip_data.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
  @tgt_ip_hash.each do |t|
    IP_data.new(t[0],t[1])
  end
end
# End lookups for tgt addresses
```

This is the error

```
undefined method `ip' for ["172.31.251.13", 24]:Array
Extracted source (around line #186):
183: 
184: <%=
185:     if @tgt_ip_hash.count > 0
186:       raw Seer::visualize(
187:                   @tgt_ip_hash,
188:                   :as => :pie_chart,
189:                   :in_element => 'tgt_pie_chart',
```

Here is the class

```
class IP_data
  attr_accessor :ip, :count

  def initialize(ip, count)
    @ip = ip
    @count = count
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually sending a hash:

```
IP_data.new({:ip => t[0],:count => t[1]})
```

Just do:

```
IP_data.new(t[0],t[1])
```

You still need the previous loop (you deleted the @tgt_ip_arrat.push in the loop), change to this:

```
  @tgt_ip_hash.each do |t|
    @tgt_ip_array.push(IP_data.new(t[0],t[1]))
  end
```

Comment: I did this, but maybe not the right way. I get this error now `undefined method 'ip' for ["172.31.251.13", 24]:Array`. I've added my full code to the main question.

Comment: The view is failing now. That's a different error. I'm answering in this same thread. Next time consider creating a new one.